# cant inject plays WS or WSClient with macwire

Tags: scala, dependency-injection, playframework-2.0

Here is what I am trying to do

```
package gc.services.http.playWs.lmi

import com.softwaremill.macwire.Macwire
import play.api.Play.current
import play.api.libs.ws._
import play.api.libs.ws.ning.NingAsyncHttpClientConfigBuilder
import scala.concurrent.Future
import play.api.libs.ws.{WSResponse, WSRequestHolder, WSClient}

import scala.concurrent.Future

class LmiWs extends Macwire{
  val baseUrl = "http://api.lmiforall.org.uk/api/v1"
  //inject plays ws client
  lazy val http = wire[WSClient]

  def getRequestHolder(url: String = baseUrl): WSRequestHolder = {
    http.url(url)
  }

  def get(request: WSRequestHolder): Future[WSResponse] = {
    request.get()
  }
}
```

If I try wire[WS] IntelliJ gives cannot resolve symbol. There are no errors shown in IntelliJ with the above but at compilation mac wire throws

> annot find constructor for WeakTypeTag[play.api.libs.ws.WSClient]

This class is just to define the base route for the app I want to hit, and it will be extended by some different classes for each particular route.  I want to be able to mock the WS dependency so that when I test this and the descendant classes I can do so without sending an actual HTTP request.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try this:

```
  lazy val http: WSClient = WS.client
```

Comment: There is no Application in scope to use that